# A question that has been already asked about overcounting but I had a doubt...

Tags: probability, combinatorics

[Overcounting when doing Counting Problems](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1884818/636998) 
This is the link to the above question. 
In the answer, we are dividing by 2 because of the two 5 groups that can be placed anywhere. But what about the two people group? 
Can this be not an arrangement? 
(1)CDEFG|(2)AB|(3)HIJKL 
Then shouldn't we devide by fact(3) instead of diving by just 2?

Answer (score 0):

It is not that we are putting the groups in order, it is that we can get the same groups by picking one and having the other left over in two ways.

If we are just forming picking a pair from four people there are six possible pairs.  If we are grouping four people into pairs there are only three ways because picking AB and leaving CD for the second pair is the same as picking CD and leaving AB for the second pair.

In the linked problem the pair is unique while the two groups of five can be swapped.

Comment: I am still not getting this. How come the pair is unique? Why it is that its position is fixed?

Comment: The pair is unique because it is the only group with two people.  If we had $n$ groups of the same size we would divide by $n!$ because we could pick them in any order and get the same set of groups.  It is just like computing the number of combinations.  When we do $n \choose r$ we divide by $r!$ because we could pick the items in any order.

Comment: So, (1)AB|(2)CDEFG|(3)HIJKL and (1)CDEFG|(2)AB|(3)HIJKL are different?

Comment: No, they are not.  We decided to pick five and then five.  We could also have picked five and then two.  That would get us the same sets of groups.  We only care about the groupings that come out.

Comment: If they would have given the same set of groups, shouldn't we divide by fact(3) but we are dividing by 2 because we are only interchanging the position of the group of 5 people?

Answer (score 0):

Think about it this way: you want 12 people split in one group of $2$ and two groups of $5$.

OK, so imagine we randomly line them up, and pick the groups as follows: the first 2 are the group of $2$, the next $5$ are a group of $5$, and the last $5$ are a group of $5$.

Now, the number of random line-ups is $12!$. OK, but this is overcounting the number of groups in two ways.

First, the people within the group can change their position in the line-up, and the same groups will result. So, you need to divide by $2!$, and twice by $5!$.

Second, the two groups of $5$ can switch positions ... and you would still have those very two groups of $5$. So, divide by $2$

So, you get:

$$\frac{12!}{2!\cdot5!\cdot5!\cdot2}$$

possible ways to make those groups.

Now, your point is that you could take that same line-up, and cut them up *differently*: for example, the first $5$ are one group of $5$, the next two are the group of $2$, and the last $5$ are a second group of $5$.  OK, yes, this would indeed be another way to get those three groups, but note that the same overcounting applies. So, if you get the three different groups *that* way, you *still* get

$$\frac{12!}{2!\cdot5!\cdot5!\cdot2}$$

possibilities for the make-up for those teams.

And if you do the line-up and pick the l;ast two people from the line-up to be hte group of $2$, you get a different way of making those teams, but again the ways in which you overcount is still the same, and hence yet again there are

$$\frac{12!}{2!\cdot5!\cdot5!\cdot2}$$

possibilities for the make-up for those teams.

So .. yes, there are $3$ ways to 'make those teams' ... (in fact, there are *far more* ways: you could pick persons 5 and 8 from the line-up to form the team of $2$, etc ...) ... but whichever *way* you make the teams,  the number of possibilities for the make-up for those teams is still the same.

Comment: yes, I am saying that we cut them up differently but what you are implying that the groups of 5 can be interchanged in any arrangement. I am having a hard time understanding why cannot we place the two group people anywhere just like the 5 people group? What makes it unique so as to fix its position?

Comment: @HardikSomani I tried to explain that you *can* place those two people anywhere. We could even, for example, pick persons 5 and 8 from the line up to go in the group of $2$, persons $1,3,4,9$, and $12$ in one group of $5$, and persons $2,6,7,10$ and $11$ in a second group of $5$. But in terms of overcounting you still need to divide by $2!\cdot5!\cdot51$ since the people within a group can swap positions without effecting the outcome of the make-ups of the groups, but you can also swap people $1,3,4,9,12$ with $2,6,7,10,11$, so you need to dive by $2$. but there is only *one* group of $2$.

Comment: So, we are basically worried about the size of the groups? Not by what it contains?

Comment: @HardikSomani We *are* worried by what it contains: Putting $A,B,C,D,E$ in a group is a different group than $A,C,D,F,G$. However, if the 'first' group of $5$ is $A,B,C,D,E$ and the 'second' is $F,G,H,I,J$, then you end up with the same two groups as when $F,G,H,I,J$ is the 'first' and $A,B,C,D,E$ is the 'second'.  That's why you divide by $2$: there are two groups of $5$, and since the groups are indistinguishable (i.e. there is no group of $5$ 'red-shirt-wearing' people and another group of $5$ 'blue-shirt-wearing' people), you overcount by $2$. But there is only *one* group of $2$.

Comment: (1)AB|(2)CDEFG|(3)HIJKL and (1)CDEFG|(2)AB|(3)HIJKL are equivalent?

Comment: @HardikSomani Yes, they are

Comment: Then shouldn't we divide fact(3) as we were only dividing by 2 to take into account the position of the group of 5 people. Because just dividing by 2 does not take into account this case which is above.

Comment: @HardikSomani No. You are confusing "ways in which you can cut up a line-up of 12 people into two groups" and "ways in which a particular cut-up leads to the same outcome".  Once you *fix* the way in which you think about the cut-up, say _ _| _ _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ _ , then you need to think relative to that cut-up. As such, (1)AB|(2)CDEFG|(3)HIJKL and (2)AB|(2)HIJKL|(3)CDEFG are equivalent ... but you don't get any equivalences with regard to the group of $2$.

Comment: (1)ABCD|(2)EFGH|(3)IJ|(4)KL <br> (1)ABCD|(2)EFGH|(3)KL|(4) <br> IJ(1)EFGH|(2)ABCD|(3)IJ|(4)KL <br> (1)ABCD|(2)EFGH|(3)KL|(4)IJ <br> There are these 4 groups for an example. These 4 are equivalent so we will divide by 4. But my question is isn't (1)KL|(2)EFGH|(3)IJ|(4)ABCD equivalent? Where are we counting this group?

Comment: @HardikSomani Yes, they are *all* equivalent ... but as far as overcounting goes: that all depends on how you are counting *in the first place*. That is, any overcount is *relative* to a count. For example, if you are counting all possible arrangement of the following form: _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ | _ _ | _ _, then you will end up overcounting by a factor of $4$, since the two groups of $4$ can be switched, and also the two groups of $2$.  But KL | EFGH | IJ | ABCD is not of the form _ _ _ _ | _ _ _ _ | _ _ | _ _  so it is therefore not overcounted, since it is not counted in the first place.